# Accented characters with knitr through a makefile

Tags: r, makefile, knitr, non-ascii-characters

I'm having problems with accented characters when compiling a .Rnw file into a .tex file using knitr in a makefile. The surprising aspect is that if I compile the same file directly inside R the problems disappear...

At some stage in my makefile I have a way to obtain .tex files from .Rnw files using knitr:

```
%.tex: %.Rnw
    Rscript \
      -e "library(knitr)" \
      -e "options(width=$(WIDTH))" \
      -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](fig.width=5,fig.height=5,fig.align='center')" \
      -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](fig.path='$(CHKFIGSDIR)/$*-')" \
      -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](cache=TRUE,cache.path='$(CACHDIR)/$*-')" \
      -e "knitr::knit('$<','$@',encoding = 'UTF-8')"
```

Then I have a particular .Rnw file where a code chunk has an accented (Portuguese) character in the name of a variable. Something like:

```
<<>>=
preçoIVA <- 240 * (1 + iva)
@
```

When a use make I get the following compilation error exactly in the "ç" character:

```
...
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |...............                                                  |  23%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                             |  31%
label: unnamed-chunk-2
Warning in block_exec(params) :
  failed to tidy R code in chunk <unnamed-chunk-2>
reason: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) : 
  <text>:1:11: unexpected '>'
1: pre<U+00E7>
              ^

Quitting from lines 95-96 (variaveis.Rnw) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:1:11: unexpected '>'
1: pre<U+00E7>
              ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... evaluate -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

Execution halted
make[1]: *** [variaveis.tex] Error 1
```

Surprisingly I able to overcome this issue if I call knit on this file directly from R:

```
> library(knitr)
> knit("variaveis.Rnw","variaveis.tex",encoding="UTF-8")


processing file: variaveis.Rnw
  |.....                                                            |   8%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........                                                       |  15%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |...............                                                  |  23%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                             |  31%
label: unnamed-chunk-2
  |.........................                                        |  38%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..............................                                   |  46%
label: unnamed-chunk-3
...
...
...    
output file: variaveis.tex

[1] "variaveis.tex"
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.10   highr_0.3      stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

Although this solves the problem, it obviously destroys the purpose of the use of the makefile (my setup involves many other files), so I would appreciate if anyone could help me in overcoming this.

Comment: Did you try the middle case, without Make, `Rscript -e "library(knitr)" -e "knit('variaveis.Rnw','variaveis.tex',encoding='UTF-8')"`?

Comment: Tried it now... and it works... strange, it seems to be something related to the makefile... the problem is that I did some further experiments and I am even more puzzled now. Full story: variaveis.Rnw is on a folder with other files and the makefile with the call to Rscript is there. If I call make in this folder no problems! But I'm calling make in another folder, where another makefile cd's to the folder with the first makefile and calls make there. And this where I get the error, not if I call make in the original folder where variaveis.Rnw is, and yes there is a reason for 2 makefiles

Comment: That's progress. Now [simplify](http://sscce.org). Minimize both makefiles. Try middle cases, like `cd folder ; make` or a rule in the second makefile that says "cd folder ; Rscript...".

Comment: The native encoding of your OS is UTF-8, so you do not really need to specify the `encoding` argument, unless you share this Makefile and Rnw document with people who use other types of OS'es that do not support UTF-8. I do not understand how the Makefile can affect `knitr` here...

Comment: Yes,  UTF-8 is not necessary, this was added already in a state of desperation ;-) And I agree that after trying what was suggested by Beta, this problem is clearly not related with knitr - this is a makefile and/or shell issue probably caused by my lack of knowledge of both

Comment: I'm becoming more and more puzzled with this issue. Here's my setup. I've a folder (folder A) with a makefile where I want to generate a presentation (normal slides and handouts) from small parts that are stored on another folder (folder B). Everything is done using beamer, knitr and R. On folder B I've a makefile that among other things generates .tex files from .Rnw files as shown in the initial post. The makefile in folder A does a very simple thing, essentially something like `cd $(SLDS_SRC_DIR); make; cd -`, where SLDS_SRC_DIR is folder B. (continues)

Comment: When I call make in folder A I get the above mentioned encoding errors, but if I cd myself on the shell to folder B and call make there I get no error! I do not understand. The purpose of the makefile in folder A is essentially to cd to folder B, run make there, and go back to folder A (actually I then copy the generated PDFs from B to A). So I do not understand how some commands executed inside a makefile, can generate different outcome when compared to executing these commands myself in the shell...